# How to piece together complex SQL queries in node-mssql

Tags: javascript, node-mssql

The MSSQL queries I want to execute will vary greatly in length in the following way:

example 1: `SELECT itemKey FROM items WHERE vendor in ('WALM', 'TARG', 'COSC')`
example 2: `SELECT itemKey FROM items WHERE vendor in ('HOMD') AND originCountry in ('USA', 'CHN')`
example 3: `SELECT itemKey FROM items WHERE vendor in ('WALM','TARG','COSC','LOWE','HOMD') and originCountry in ('USA','CHN','TAI','VIE')`

to accomplish this I use this to build my "filter" if you will:

```
filter += ' AND vendor in ('
    while(i < vendors.length) {
      if(i == (vendors.length - 1)) {
        filter += '\'' + vendors[i] + '\')'
      }else{
        filter += '\'' + vendors[i] + '\','
      }
      i++
    }
```

followed by: (I used squiggles to replace backticks for this post)

`const result = await sql.query~SELECT itemKeys FROM items WHERE ${filter}~`

However doing it this way produces the following error:

[stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afl0E.png)

Where as this following works perfectly:
`const result = await sql.query~SELECT itemKeys FROM items WHERE vendor in ('TARG')`

In the bottom section of the above post, I explained the 'hard coded' query I'm using to verify that no other parts of my code are broken.

The stack trace for the non-working section of code is snipped as a photo.

Comment: Put all the conditions in an array. Then use `array.join()` to concatenate them with `AND` as the separator.

Comment: Don't substitute variables into the SQL string, use `?` parameters.

Comment: This doesn't work if `vendors` is empty, and is susceptible to SQL injections. Doesn't node-mysql support parameterised queries?!